# spring cloud config custom path

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

git structure

```
/--|
   |--/tenant-name1|
                   - tenant-name1.properties
   |
   |--/tenant-name2|
                   - tenant-name2.properties
```

i using props from single app but with multiple tenants. Tenants can be applied to project in runtime. All tenants properties in their own folder.

**How i can configure path for get properties for tenantX?**

tried different variants like
localhost:8888/tenantX/tenantX.properties

my spring cloud application.yaml

```
server.port: 8888
spring:
  profiles:
    active: git
  cloud.config:
    server:
      git:
        uri: https://gitlab.some.path.git
        search-paths: '{application}'
        username: dummy
        password: dummy
        default-label: release-candidate
```

Answer (score 2):

just adding property

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: {application}
```

and for application= tenantA it will be search in /tenantA/* folder

`native` using due underlying git cloned into local (into some /tmp/ fodler) and searching file via native (aka FileSystem repository)